# Secure RTP stream for android devices

Tags: android, stream, rtsp, rtp, sdp

I am trying to stream live and VOD content onto the android devices. For that I am writing a RTSP server which will stream through RTP protocol using SDP. I want to send the data in a secure way to my client (android device). I read in RFC of SDP that it supports encryption key and method (field k=*) but it says it is not recommended. Also I am not sure whether android device will be able to decode the encrypted stream by reading the encryption key and method from the SDP file. I have also checked SRTP(Secure RTP) RFC but was not able to find any method from android API reference which can read the SRTP stream.

I want to know what is the best way to go ahead and transmit encrypted data to the android device using the RTP/SRTP stream.

Thanks in advance,

Siddharth

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Im interested in this.

Comment: We were not able to solve this. By the time we were developing this, the android market moved largely to version 3.x or higher which inherently supports HLS protocol. So ultimately we went ahead and implemented HLS only for android as well.